# Problem on Trigonometry and Similar triangles

Tags: geometry

E is the midpoint of segment XZ.  The vertical segment ED perpendicular to segment XC is 2 units long.  Segment DC is 4 units long.  Angle $\theta$ measures $30^\circ$.

What is the length of segment XZ? It seems to be an angle and/or similar triangles but I am not sure.

I am familiar with finding the value of one side of similar triangles when one needs to redraw them separately when one triangle is inside of another triangle.

[image: Triangle]

Answer (score 2):

Since $\sin30^\circ=\dfrac{1}{2}=\dfrac{DE}{XE}$,  $XE=4$, and since $\tan30^\circ=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}=\dfrac{DE}{XD}$,  $XD=2\sqrt{3}$.

Since $E$ is the midpoint of $XZ$ then $EZ=4$.

So $XZ=8$.

Note that the point $C$ and the segment $DC$ are irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you.  That is correct.  And as you note, point C and segment DC are irrelevant but in the problem I was given angle <XCZ is a right angle.

Comment: Perhaps that was to temp you to try to work it a harder way.

Answer (score 1):

Since you know the angle $\theta$ and the length of the segment $ED$, you can get the length of $XE$ and then multiply it by $2$ (because $E$ is the midpoint of $XZ$) and get what you are looking for:
$$XZ=2 \cdot XE = 2 \cdot \frac{ED}{\sin\theta}=2 \cdot \frac{2}{\frac{1}{2}}=8$$